# Two similar copy codes with Java, two behaviors

Tags: java, io, java-io

So I wanted to implement a function that copies a file into a new file of which I'll specify the directory (I'll create it) and then, as I found on stackoverflow, use the **Files.copy** function of apache.commons to do the trick.

My problem is the following : I write two codes, one that works and the other don't, except they are so similar I seem not to capture the difference...

Here's the code for the first method :

```
public static void copyToFile2 (String firmFolderName, String allFirmsFolderName, String copy_file_name, String copied_file_name) throws IOException {

        File from = new File(copied_file_name) ;
        String pathOfDirectoryOfToFile= "Folder/" + allFirmsFolderName +"/" + firmFolderName ; 
        //String pathOfDirectoryOfToFile = "Folder/fomrs/firm/" ;
        String pathOfToFile = pathOfDirectoryOfToFile + "/" + copy_file_name ; 

        (new File(pathOfDirectoryOfToFile)).mkdir();
        File to = new File(pathOfToFile) ;

        Files.copy( from.toPath(), to.toPath() );

    }
```

In this one, I have to specify few parameters that will forge a path to a directory, create that directory and finally create the copy file in there. It throws a NoSuchFileException, and while I know the file doesn't not exist, I thought it might be nice and create it itself, but since it didn't : I went ahead and added `to.createNewFile();` right after the to file instanciation to make sure, thus I'll have the following code :

```
(new File(pathOfDirectoryOfToFile)).mkdir();
File to = new File(pathOfToFile) ;
to.createNewFile();

Files.copy( from.toPath(), to.toPath() );
```

With this one, I get  an IOException stating that the specified access path is not found !

Second method :

```
public static void copyToFile1 (String firmFolderName, String allFirmsFolderName, String copy_file_name, String copied_file_name) throws IOException {

        File from = new File(copied_file_name) ;
        String pathOfDirectoryOfToFile= "Folder/" + allFirmsFolderName +"/" + firmFolderName +"/" ; 
        String pathOfToFile = pathOfDirectoryOfToFile + "/" + copy_file_name ; 

        (new File("Folder/mdjs55/")).mkdir();
        File to = new File("Folder/mdjs55/tm.jsp" ) ;


        Files.copy( from.toPath(), to.toPath() );

    }
```

In this one works fine.

So what is it ? The only difference I can not is that the path in the copyToFile2 is dynamic and in the second static, but how is that supposed to be a problem ? For what I know it's merely a string that's being build...

P.S : I used System.out.println(to.toPath()) to check out the path for that, it's well constructed.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: Mentionned two exceptions in the question : NoSuchFile and IOException.

Comment: Files.copy now is in Java 7. `Files.copy(from.toPath(), to.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);` might be useful.

Comment: @JoopEggen : didn't know that, does it have the same mechanism of the File.copy in apache.commons ? How different are they ?

Comment: Java generations are continuously integrating general libraries, though often revised. `java.nio.file.Files` uses Path parameters and are you sure, you are not already using that one? FileUtils is from apache commons I/O and quite different.

Comment: I got this exception for the File.copy line :  `java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException`, so I think it's the java.nio.file.Files . Would you recommend the Java Files.copy ?

Comment: Just tried your suggestion and it works perfect : `Files.copy(from.toPath(), to.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);` works just fine. But I had to use this two imports : `import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;` , so not sure if I understood you the first time (because I thought I had only to import `import java.io.File;`, which didn't work for me).

Comment: Sorry for terseness/obscurity on my side.

Comment: @JoopEggen : didn't mean it that way, it's more to do with my neophytic nature, and thank you for your valuable indications :)

Comment: You don't need the createNewFile() calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path in the second example is shorter. `mkdir()` will only create one sub-directory so if you go two sub-directories it will fail and when you try to use a file in that directory it will also fail.

I suspect what you want is `mkdirs()` which creates multiple-levels of directories as required.

Comment: Oh, limited knowledge made me ignore that possibility, I'll try that and give you a feed back !

Comment: @Gloserio I think if anyone knew 10% of all there is to know about Java it would be fatal ;)

Comment: Well, tried that out and it sure does create the directory(ies), but the File.copy is now angry as it throws this exception : java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: Folder\forms1\firms8\copy_jiji___1.jsp , quite funny because I made sure that neither that directory nor the name of copy file exist...

Comment: What sort of file system are you using? If it's Windows based you might find it doesn't like certain file names.

Comment: Still curious though : why did mkdir() work in copyFile1 and not in the copyFile2 ?

Comment: 10% is too much, my goal for the year is 0.1% :p

Comment: mkdir() will fail if the directory already exists, or you don't have permissions, or the path is a bit odd.  I am not sure which might apply in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
String pathOfDirectoryOfToFile= "Folder/" + allFirmsFolderName +"/" + firmFolderName +"/" ; 
String pathOfToFile = pathOfDirectoryOfToFile + "/" + copy_file_name ;
```

looks suspicious. It produces

```
"Folder/" + allFirmsFolderName +"/" + firmFolderName +"//" + copy_file_name ;
```

Comment: Oh sorry I had that mistake but took it off, seems I pasted an old code. Still I can assure you that even with this mistake taken away, my question holds as is !

Comment: I've made the edit, thanks for mention it though @Evgeniy Dorofeev